# How to import css from libraries via postCSS?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, postcss, flickity

I am using this library for slideshows called [Flickity](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/) that requires to use its css file `flickity.min.css`. In my project I use postCSS and when including this `flickity.min.css` into my components css like:

```
@import ./lib/flickity.min
```

its classes get prefixed in the following way: `MyComponent__flickity-class_35aw` issue with this is that flickity creates new dom elements and relies on its classes, so in inspector the class for it would be `.flickity-class` hence no styles are applied to it, I'm trying to figure out how to include it correctly.

Using react + webpack setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're importing the CSS as [CSS Modules](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#css-modules). If you didn't intend to use CSS Modules you just need to remove 'modules' from your webpack config, i.e.

```
loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: 'style!css?modules'
    }
]
```

Should just become:

```
loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: 'style!css'
    }
]
```

If however you want to use CSS modules for some files but not others I would recommend defining multiple CSS loader configs based on an appropriate heuristic, e.g. assuming your /lib/ directory will only ever contain 'global' CSS you could do this:

```
loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /lib/,
        loaders: 'style!css?modules'   
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /lib/,
        loaders: 'style!css'
    }
]
```